# how to make a class visible when checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

i have a list with 3 different categories, and i need to have them be hidden or visible depending on if a checkbox is checked or not.

my html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="one">One<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="two">Two<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="three">Three<br>
<ul>
    <li class='one'>alpha</li>
    <li class='two'>beta</li>
    <li class='three'>gamma</li>
</ul>
```

how would i get it so that when checkbox One is selected, only .one is visible? and if One and Two are selected .one and .two are visible.

Comment: if one and two are checked then?

Comment: whatever checkboxes are selected, i would like to be visible. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Then try

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function () {
    //element and attribute equals selector to select all input elements with name option and register a change event handelr
    $('input[name="option"]').change(function () {
        //find the target element using class selector and the changed checkbox's value and then use toggle() to set visibility according to the checked state of the checkbox
        $('.' + this.value).toggle(this.checked)
    }).change(); //trigger the change event on page load to set the proper initial values
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/stsyY/)

Comment: You have to hide the lis before!

Comment: @LarsEbert not required since the change event is triggered manually on page load see the fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I was a little fast. When I commented, it was not triggered manually.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that with checkboxes, the user can select multiple options!

```
$('ul li').hide();
$('input').change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.' + $(this).attr('value')).show();
    } else {
        $('.' + $(this).attr('value')).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/8843J/)

**HTML**

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="one" name="option" value="one">One<br>
<input type="checkbox" class='two' name="option" value="two">Two<br>
<input type="checkbox" class='three' name="option" value="three">Three<br>
<ul>
    <li class='one' style="display:none;">alpha</li>
    <li class='two' style="display:none;">beta</li>
    <li class='three' style="display:none;">gamma</li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
$('li.'+$(this).attr('class')).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery would be this simplest method but this can be done with CSS.

NB. This method is not flexible and HTML structure specific

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wcxDj)

**HTML**

```
<input class='one' type="checkbox" name="option1" value="one">One<br>
<input class='two' type="checkbox" name="option2" value="two">Two<br>
<input class='three' type="checkbox" name="option3" value="three">Three<br>
<ul>
    <li class='one'>alpha</li>
    <li class='two'>beta</li>
    <li class='three'>gamma</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox].one:checked ~ ul li.one,
input[type=checkbox].two:checked ~ ul li.two,
input[type=checkbox].three:checked ~ ul li.three  {
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like : http://jsfiddle.net/84sAy/

```
$('input').each(function(){
$(this).change(function(checked){
console.log()
    if ($(this)[0].checked)
{
  $("."+$(this).val()).hide()
}
    else
    {
         $("."+$(this).val()).show()
    }
})
```

})